# retrieve parent component ref for a hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've found myself needing to retrieve the element `ref` for **every** parent component that my hook, `useExample`, is used in. However, I'm stumped as to how I might be able to retrieve something like this or how to even check if there is an element to target?

Usually I would just do something a little *"hacky"* in a functional component like so:

```
const Example = WrappedComponent => {
    const ref = createRef();
    return <WrappedComponent ref={ref} />;
};
```

However, due to it being a `hook` and returning information and *not* a component, I can't target any component, and thus I'm very stumped.

#### My current code:

```
const useExample = () => {
    const [stateValue, setStateValue] = useState("example");
    useEffect(() => {
        // Run some code...
    }, []);

    return stateValue;
};

const Component = () => {
    const data = useExample();
    return (
        <div> /* <--- How do I gain access to this element */
             <span>{ data }</span>
        </div>
    );
};
```

I could probably pass a created `ref` which has been attached to the parent `div` as a parameter to `useExample`, however this feels cheap and hacky, and I feel there should be a much easier solution.

In the ideal world something like this would be amazing:

```
const ref = React.getParentRef();
```

Apologies if there is an obvious answer in the documentation, I'm very new to **React** and am unsure of the correct question to be asking or what to be looking for in order to find it in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the ref from the hook

```
const useExample = () => {
    const myRef = React.useRef(null)
    const [stateValue, setStateValue] = useState("example");
    useEffect(() => {
        // Run some code...
    }, []);

    return [myRef , stateValue];
};

const Component = () => {
    const [myRef , data] = useExample();
    return (
        <div ref={myRef}> /* <--- How do I gain access to this element */
             <span>{ data }</span>
        </div>
    );
};
```

If data can be a component:

```
const useExample = () => {
  const myRef = React.useRef(null);
  const [stateValue, setStateValue] = React.useState("example");
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const parent = myRef?.current?.parentNode;
    console.log(parent);
  }, []);

  return <div ref={myRef}>{stateValue}</div>;
};

const Component = () => {
  const data = useExample();

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{data}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return <Component />;
}
```

But then you have to access the parent node from the ref, I believe this may cause problems as a component is being returned, and its anti pattern

Comment: Trying to avoid cheap work-arounds if I can. Having to apply this to **all** components seems very boiler-platey.

Comment: With just the way specified in OP I believe its impossible, there is no way to know the parent element of a child you render {data} in it(maybe if data can be a component), unless you mean the first parent node rendered by the component, but it would also involve a wrapping component or similar